# Sorting by relevance performance issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, relevance

Is there a function / method within mongoose (and or mongodb) which could be used to sort a queries results based on relevance (highest number of matching query params)?

The example below is what I am using at the moment (the query uses `$in:[]`, otherwise the same) - my collection is quite small so performance is fine but on larger collections it slows things down dramatically.

Alternatively, if there is a better performing method (outside of mongoose / mongodb) I'd be happy to know about it.

Example:

```
var docs = [
    {
        fruits: ['apple', 'orange', 'tomato'],
        colors: ['blue', 'green'],
        // relevance: 3
    },
    {
        fruits: ['apple', 'carrot'],
        colors: ['red', 'green'],
        // relevance: 2
    }
]

var query = {fruits: ['apple', 'orange'], colors: ['green']}

docs.forEach(function(doc){
    var relevance = 0
    Object.keys(query).forEach(function(_query){
        var arrays = [doc[_query], query[_query]]
        var result = arrays.shift().filter(function(v) {
            return arrays.every(function(a) {
                return a.indexOf(v) !== -1;
            });
        });
        relevance += result.length
    })
    doc.relevance = relevance
})
```

Result:

```
var docs = [
    {
        fruits: ['apple', 'orange', 'tomato'],
        colors: ['blue', 'green'],
        relevance: 3
    },
    {
        fruits: ['apple', 'carrot'],
        colors: ['red', 'green'],
        relevance: 2
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you also add the expected output?

Comment: Using `arrays.shift()` and `arrays.every` on an array that always contains exactly two items hardly makes sense.

Comment: @Bergi there are a dozen or so arrays which may be used in the query, the use of `.shift()` and `.every()` is to cover a dynamically built query.

Comment: @brod: you are not building `arrays` dynamically…

Comment: @Bergi I must not understand what I am doing then, I'll go over it again

Comment: I would start by looking at performance. Simple implementation gives us exponential performance: `O(docs ^ keys ^ vals)`

One common optimization strategy is to use hashes instead of arrays. Hash lookup operation takes constant time.

If we could transform the data model to use hashes exclusively in less than exponential time, we can significantly improve the overall performance of the algorithm, close to linear time. (length of docs).

Comment: Seems to me you want *some* (any match) not *every* (every element must match).

Comment: @RobG: Given that `arrays` has exactly one member, it doesn't make a difference - in fact it should be omitted altogether.

Comment: @JayZelenkov: Nope, there's nothing exponential here. It's a simple product: `O(|docs| * |query| * |params/doc|)`. But yes, hashing `query` would work.

Comment: @Bergi thanks! It is a product.

Comment: @Bergi I understand what you were saying about `.shift(), .every()` - not sure why I ever thought it was needed.

Comment: @Bergi—in the first iteration at the point of `arrays.every(...)`, *arrays* will be *query.fruits*, which has two members (`['apple',' orange']`). The OP is testing to see how many of those appear in *docs.fruits* using *indexOf*. Using *every* will return false unless every member matches, whereas it should be *some*.

Comment: @RobG: No, `arrays` willl be `[query.fruits, docs[0].fruits]`.

Comment: @Bergi—so *shift* didn't do anything?

Comment: @RobG: `shift` will remove the first element, so that he'd essentially do `query.fruits.filter(v => [docs[0].fruits].every(a => a.indexOf…`. Now you can see why `every` is pointless.

Comment: @Bergi—at that point *arrays* is `[docs[0].fruits]`, i.e. `[['apple', 'orange']]`. I was missing that outer array and thinking *every* was iterating over `['apple', 'orange']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with aggregation:

```js
db.getCollection('docs').aggregate([
{$match: {fruits: {$in: ['apple', 'orange']}, colors: {$in: ['green']}}},
{$project: {
    relevance: {
        $sum: [
          {$cond: {if: { "$setIsSubset": [['orange'], "$fruits" ]}, then: 1, else: 0}},
          {$cond: {if: { "$setIsSubset": [['apple'], "$fruits" ]}, then: 1, else: 0}},
          {$cond: {if: { "$setIsSubset": [['green'], "$colors" ]}, then: 1, else: 0}}]
    },
    doc: '$$ROOT'}}
])
```

result:

```js
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57be8a9b65d2835e960df543"),
    "relevance" : 3,
    "doc" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("57be8a9b65d2835e960df543"),
        "fruits" : [ 
            "apple", 
            "orange", 
            "tomato"
        ],
        "colors" : [ 
            "blue", 
            "green"
        ]
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57be8aa865d2835e960df544"),
    "relevance" : 2,
    "doc" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("57be8aa865d2835e960df544"),
        "fruits" : [ 
            "apple", 
            "carrot"
        ],
        "colors" : [ 
            "red", 
            "green"
        ]
    }
}
```